# How to copy/clone an interface pointer?

Tags: go

I'm trying to make a copy of a pointer received as interface{}. Any idea how to do that? I've tried Reflect.Value.Interface() but it returns the pointer/ address itself instead to return its value (deference). I'm also wondering if there is a signifiant performance loss as I'm planning doing this kind of copy vs simple pointer deference.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type str struct {
    field string
}

func main() {
    s := &str{field: "astr"}
    a := interface{}(s)
    v := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    s.field = "changed field"
    b := v.Interface()
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/rFmJGrLVaa

Comment: If you know the type, why not just use a type assertion?

Comment: @JimB, but I don't know it, thus the reason why there is an interface{}.

Answer (score 5):

You need [reflect.Indirect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Indirect), and also to set `b` before changing `s.field`.

Here is some working code :

https://play.golang.org/p/PShhvwXjdG

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type str struct {
    field string
}

func main() {

    s := &str{field: "astr"}
    a := interface{}(s)

    v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(a))
    b := v.Interface()

    s.field = "changed field"

    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```